# cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'system,DateTime'

Tags: c#

i am creating a project .
i want to download the files from ftp .
i can download it but only by todays date in dateTimePicker1.
it only downloads systems date.
my code is

```
txtSelectedDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
dateTimePicke1.Value = DateTime.NoW;
```

can anyone say me how to download files by selecting date in dateTimePicker1 not by Current date.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to clarify the relationship between the DateTimePicker and the concept of FTP downloading.

Comment: There is no implicit way to convert!  Howevr as @Biggs answer there is a explicit way to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Select a different date on the control "dateTimePicker1"
use the code below:

```
txtSelectedDate.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

or

```
txtSeletedDate.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

DateTimePicker allows you to change the date you are using and you should not use DateTime.Now, you shall assign the selected date to your text property.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the DateTime.ParseExact command, like so:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null);
```

If you assign that to your dateTimePicker1 you will be able to give it any date.